# How can I zero pad a 4 character string in C#

Tags: c#

I am using the following class method to create a Base36 string from a number:

```
private const string CharList = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public static String Encode(long input) {
    if (input < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input", input, "input cannot be negative");
        char[] clistarr = CharList.ToCharArray();
        var result = new Stack<char>();
        while (input != 0)
        {
            result.Push(clistarr[input % 36]);
            input /= 36;
        }
        return new string(result.ToArray());
    }
```

One of the requirements is that the string should always be padded with zero's and should be a maximum of four digits. Can anyone suggest a way that I can code the leading zero's and also limit the function so it will never return more than "ZZZZ" ? Is there some function in C# that can do this. Sorry about the indentation on this code. I am not sure why it's not indenting properly.

Comment: You can index into the string directly, there's no need to convert it to an array beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are always going to be *exactly* four digits, it's really easy:

```
const long MaxBase36Value = (36L * 36L * 36L * 36L) - 1L;

public static string EncodeBase36(long input)
{
    if (input < 0L || input > MaxBase36Value)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    char[] chars = new char[4];
    chars[3] = CharList[(int) (input % 36)];
    chars[2] = CharList[(int) ((input / 36) % 36)];
    chars[1] = CharList[(int) ((input / (36 * 36)) % 36)];
    chars[0] = CharList[(int) ((input / (36 * 36 * 36)) % 36)];
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Or using a loop:

```
const long MaxBase36Value = (36L * 36L * 36L * 36L) - 1L;

public static string EncodeBase36(long input)
{
    if (input < 0L || input > MaxBase36Value)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    char[] chars = new char[4];
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        chars[i] = CharList[(int) (input % 36)];
        input = input / 36;            
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks very much

Comment: I have a couple of error messages: chars[i] = input % 36; gives a message Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: return new string[chars]; gives a message: Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'int'

Comment: Hello. Still getting an error: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int' for the line: chars[i] = CharList[input % 36];

Comment: @Melissa: Gah, okay - check now.

Answer (score 5):

ZZZZ in base 36 is 1679615 in base 10 (36^4 - 1). So you can simply test if the number is greater than this and reject it.

To pad you can use [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx).

Comment: Of course, that's a nicer way of expressing the maximum value. Doh :)